# What does "(any sword)" mean in terms of Magic Items?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items

In the *Dungeon Master's Guide* section for [Magic Items (Chapter 7)](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/dmg/treasure#MagicItems), a lot of items have a requirement that says (any ___), specifically weapons and maybe armor if I remember correctly. For example, Flame Tongue says: “Weapon (any sword)”. Is this just to classify what the Item can be, or can you use another Magic Item in this place? Personally, I think a Vicious, Flame Tongue, Dragon Slayer, Vorpal Sword would be dope, but I'm not sure if that would work.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

#### This refers to the type of weapon, not that it can be a particular magic weapon.

This is explained in the *Dungeon Master's Guide*, in the section [Magic Item Categories](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/dmg/treasure#MagicItemCategories):

> Some magic weapons specify the type of weapon they are in their descriptions, such as a longsword or longbow. If a magic weapon doesn’t specify its weapon type, you may choose *the type* or determine it randomly.

Similarly for armor:

> Some suits of magic armor specify the type of armor they are, such as chain mail or plate. If a magic armor doesn’t specify its armor type, you may choose *the type* or determine it randomly.

This is important because each enchantment has an assigned rarity to it, for example, a [Weapon of Warning](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/weapon-of-warning) is uncommon. A Vicious Flame Tongue Dragon Slayer Vorpal Sword *would* be dope, but its rarity would be the sum (product?) of rare, rare, rare, and legendary, and I'm not sure what that even means.

#### You can make a Vorpalicious Dragon's Tongue if you want.

To be clear, if you're the DM and you want to give one of your players a Vicious Flame Tongue Dragon Slayer Vorpal Sword, go right ahead. If your party is level 20, balance started to lose its meaning a while ago.

The DMG does mention this possibility in [Chapter 9: Dungeon Master's Workshop](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/dmg/dungeon-masters-workshop#ModifyinganItem):

> You can also modify an item by fusing it with properties from another item. For example, you could combine the effects of a helm of comprehending languages with those of a helm of telepathy into a single helmet. This makes the item more powerful (and probably increases its rarity), but it won’t break your game.

The use case given here, Helm of Telepathically Comprehending Languages, likely won't break your game, but your Vorpalicious Dragon's Tongue might, so just be careful.

Comment: So you're saying the DM should *not* allow the party to acquire a Flaming Raging Poisoning Sword of Doom at level 10?

Comment: I'm not saying you *shouldn't* give it to them, but I'm definitely not saying you *should*.

Comment: I don't plan on giving it to anyone. I just gave a dope example because that was the dopest thing I could think of. That being said, I wonder how the party would react to a BBEG with that.....  *evil dm laugh*

Comment: @Deus They would probably cast *heat metal* on the sword until he dropped it, then pick it up and kill him with it.

Comment: @ThomasMarkov sure, if they have a spare hour to attune to it...

Comment: Only the Vorpal and Flame tongue enchantments would require attunement. Vicious and Dragonslayer shouldnt.

Comment: @ThomasMarkov as a dm i know my players aren't smart enough to think of that. But as a player, thanks for the tip. That is really smart